# TypeError: context must be a dict rather than RequestContext

Tags: python, django-templates

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Esk5x.png)

TypeError at /polls
context must be a dict rather than RequestContext.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls
Django Version: 4.1.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
context must be a dict rather than RequestContext.

Comment: Hi, can you please copy your code into your post? Thanks

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the `render` shortcut:

```py
def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list})
```